# <select> element and observe('click') on options to toggle option.selected

Tags: javascript, dom, prototypejs

I've seen a few examples using jQuery that do what I want, but I'm developing a plugin for an application that uses the Prototype framework and would like to stick to that.

Basically, I want the functionality as if the ctrl key was always pressed. If a selected option is clicked, I want it to de-select.

Here's an example I found using jQuery: http://jsbin.com/idofa

Here's my version that doesn't work, because the event fires *after* the default action selects it (which results in it selecting and then immediately being unselected).

```
option.observe('click', function(event){
    this.selected = !this.selected;
});
```

I have tried adding event.stop(); and event.preventDefault(); neither of which seem to have an effect.

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but `this.selected = ! this.selected`.

Comment: @eulogy Did you try to replace "click" by "mousedown"?? Also, the `event.stop()` is not only a good idea, it seems necessary! Then you have to add something like `this.select()` and `this.unselect()`

Comment: @lajarre That was it! I didn't think I could use mousedown there.

Comment: Note that options can be selected without clicking on them using keyboard navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Proper answer, from comment I made above:

Selection is performed on mousedown, so **`'mousedown'` event has to be used instead of `'click'` here.**

```
option.observe('mousedown', function (event) {
    this.selected = !this.selected;
    event.stop();    // unnecessary in this case, but I think it's good practice
});
```

​
Example on a fiddle, edited by Victor:

http://jsfiddle.net/RP7em/3/

Comment: even better: http://jsfiddle.net/RP7em/3/ - using single event handler on `select`